# Java: Should I construct lightweight objects each time or cache instance?

Tags: java, performance, object, caching, memory

During code review, a colleague of mine looked at this piece of code:

```
public List<Item> extractItems(List<Object[]> results) { 
    return Lists.transform(results, new Function<Object[], Item>() {
        @Override
        public Item apply(Object[] values) {
            ...
        }
    });
}
```

He suggests changing it to this:

```
public List<Item> extractItems(List<Object[]> results) { 
    return Lists.transform(results, getTransformer());
}

private Function<Object[], Item> transformer;

private Function<Object[], Item> getTransformer() {
    if(transformer == null) {
        transformer = new Function<Object[], Item>() {
            @Override
            public Item apply(Object[] values) {
                ...
             }
        };
    }
    return transformer;
 }
```

So we are looking at taking the `new Function()` construction, and moving it over to be a member variable and re-used next time.

While I understand his logic and reasoning, I guess I'm not sold that I should do this for every possible object that I create that follows this pattern.  It seems like there would be some good reasons not to do this, but I'm not sure.

What are your thoughts?  Should we always cache duplicately created objects like this?

*UPDATE*

The `Function` is a google guava thing, and holds no state.  A couple people have pointed out the non-thread-safe aspect of this change, which is perfectly valid, but isn't actually a concern here.  I'm more asking about the practice of constructing vs caching small objects, which is better?

Comment: The question here seems subjective, it's likely better placed on [Code Review Exchange](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 2):

Your colleague's proposal is not thread safe. It also reeks of premature optimization. Is the construction of a `Function` object a known (tested) CPU bottleneck? If not, there's no reason to do this. It's not a memory problem - you're not keeping a reference, so GC will sweep it away, probably from Eden.

Comment: Precisely what I was going to say. +1 for the thread safety. It's now marginally faster and substantially less safe to use!

Comment: The `new Function()` is google guava stuff, and holds no state, so even if two threads created two objects, and only the second stuck around, we don't much care.  I almost put in the question to "ignore the non-thread-safety aspect of the change", but your points are valid for sure (I saw the same thing).  My question is more aimed at "all things equal, is it better to save off the instances instead of recreate them each time".

Comment: @SeanAdkinson I'm sticking with premature optimization. You're trading less CPU usage for more memory usage without any idea if either is significant.

Answer (score 0):

As already said, it's all premature optimization. The gain is probably not measurable and the whole story should be forgotten.

However, with the `transformer` being stateless, I'd go for it for readability reasons. Anonymous functions as an argument rather pollute the code.

Just drop the lazy initialization - you're gonna use the `transformer` whenever you use the class, right? (*) So put it in a `static final` field and maybe you can reuse it somewhere else.

---

(*) And even if not, creating and holding a *cheap* object during the whole application lifetime doesn't matter.